# change weblogic jdk to 64 bit cause slow web page loading

Tags: java, weblogic

I used weblogic as application server,listen port is 7001, JDK is 32 bit.

Recently , I need to change my weblogic JDK from 32 bit to 64 bit, when I finish this，my web page loading became very very slow.I found if I change the listen port to 7002, web page loading will became fast.

In my production enviroment,I can't change the listen port.So how to investigate and solve this problem?

Comment: simple way of investigating, is to check the memory usage. Also, check whether you have enabled to used 64-bit flag or not.

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic defines two listen ports. One for regular, non secure requests (via`HTTP`) and other for secure requests (via`HTTPS`)

> 1. 7001 - HTTP
> 2. 7002 - HTTPS

If you already configured the JDK path in weblogic, Please check whether it is updated in Manged Server.